# Неправильно происходит запись строки в БД

Tags: c++, кодировка, qt5

QT5 C++ ANSI кодировка внутри UTF-8. Проблема в следующем.

```
    string = "ы"; 
    char = string[0].unicode();
```

Выводит код 75 и при записи в БД SQL с форматом UTF-8 выдаёт вопросы. Что порекомендуете в этом случае?

OC Ubuntu, QTCreator, mysql 14.4.

```
QString create_sql_add_2 (QString name, QString value)
{   // создадим запрос SQL для добавления адреса в БД
    QString x;
    QSqlQuery query_mysql(QSqlDatabase::database("dbsql"));

    QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
    QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(codec);
    QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(codec);
    QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(codec);

    x = "INSERT INTO addressbook (name, email) "
              "VALUES ('";
    x += name; x += "', '"; x += value;
    x += "');";
    x = cp1251_utf8(x);
//  cout << x.toStdString() << endl;


    if (!query_mysql.exec(x)){cout << "bad " << x.toStdString() << endl;}
    return x;
}
QString cp1251_utf8 (QString cpp1251)
{
    QTextDecoder decoder(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
    QString result, buf; QChar ch1;
    QByteArray bytearray;
    result.clear();
    bytearray.append(cpp1251);

    for (int i = 0; i < bytearray.size(); i++) {
       // if (decoder.toUnicode(bytearray.constData() + i, 1) != "'")
      //  {
            result += decoder.toUnicode(bytearray.constData() + i, 1);
            buf = "ы"; //result.right(1);
            ch1 = buf[0].unicode();
            //if (ch1 )
            if (result.isEmpty()) {
               break; // we got our character !
            }

         //cout << i << result.toStdString()<< endl;
     //   }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Стоит отметить, что перед записью в БД формируется строка:

```
INSERT INTO addressbook (name, email) VALUES ('Иван Иванов', 'ivan-ivanov@mail.ru');
```

Comment: для начала нужно привести код, который компилируется.

Comment: Что за БД? Как Вы пишите в БД? Что за IDE используете? Какая ОС?

Comment: Сравнивайте используемые кодировки в ОС и БД.

Comment: содержимое переменных смотрел в дебагере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем дело было так, зашёл я в консоль mysql, подключился к БД и ввёл команду

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "character_set_database";
```

Оказалось что БД работает с кодировкой latin1. Перевёл её в utf8

```
ALTER TABLE `job_db`.`addressbook` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

И все новые записи стали ложиться как надо. Всем выражаю признательность за оказанную помощь.